# ResetBindings() does not update BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have problem updating `DataSource` of a `DataGridView` in WindowsForms application.

I have `DataGridView` populated by data in `List` of my own class `Skoleni`.

```
private List<Skoleni> setrideneSkoleni; //list of objects
```

In MainForm() method, I call following:

```
 bindingDwgSkoleni = new BindingSource(); //create bindingsource
 bindingDwgSkoleni.DataSource = setrideneSkoleni; //set datasource for bindingsource
 dgwSkoleni.DataSource = bindingDwgSkoleni; // set datasource for datagridview
```

Which sets `DataSource` for both `BindingSource` and `DataGridView`.

Then I add item to`setrideneSkoleni` in additional form, the button_Click method contains this:

```
setrideneSkoleni.Update(); // updates setrideneSkoleni
bindingDwgSkoleni.ResetBindings(false); //should update bindingSource, but DOES NOT
```

Variable `setrideneSkoleni` is updated (item is added), but BindingSource is not (checked in debug - list still contains the same items).

I can not simply set DataSource of DataGridView to null and than to new list, because it destroys formatting (hidden columns become visible, sorting is cancelled), I have to use BindingSource to keep the configuration.

Can anyone advice me how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I use similar code and it's working on my side. Have you tried using a BindingList instead of a List?

Comment: I have solved this by assigning new sorted list to ``BindingSource.DataSource`` each time I need the data updated - it keeps the formatting and works fine.

Comment: Does your `Skoleni` implemet `INotifyProperty`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `List` to `BindableList`. Implement `INotifyProperty` on `Skoleni` class.